# Python 3.9: Why I can't import angr

Tags: python, angr

Installed **angr** module to Python3.9. Trying to run program, I get this error (I'm using Kali linux, if it's significant here):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vasyok03/Downloads/angr_basic_solver.py", line 1, in <module>
    import angr
  File "/home/vasyok03/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/angr/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .procedures import SIM_PROCEDURES, SimProcedures, SIM_LIBRARIES
  File "/home/vasyok03/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/angr/procedures/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .procedure_dict import SIM_PROCEDURES, SimProcedures
  File "/home/vasyok03/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/angr/procedures/procedure_dict.py", line 15, in <module>
    for pkg_name, package in autoimport.auto_import_packages('angr.procedures', path, skip_dirs):
  File "/home/vasyok03/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/angr/misc/autoimport.py", line 26, in auto_import_packages
    for name, mod in auto_import_modules('%s.%s' % (base_module, lib_module_name), lib_path, ignore_files=ignore_files):
  File "/home/vasyok03/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/angr/misc/autoimport.py", line 40, in auto_import_modules
    proc_module = importlib.import_module(".%s" % proc_module_name, base_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/vasyok03/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/angr/procedures/linux_kernel/sysinfo.py", line 5, in <module>
    sysinfo_ty = parse_type("""
  File "/home/vasyok03/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/angr/sim_type.py", line 1555, in parse_type
    parser.cparser = pycparser.ply.yacc.yacc(module=parser,
AttributeError: module 'pycparser' has no attribute 'ply'
```

I was hoping it's popular error and I would find solution in internet, but didn't find anything.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-dev libffi-dev build-essential virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: you need to use `virtual env`

Comment: "In general, don't expect support for problems arising from installing angr outside of a virtualenv" -- from https://docs.angr.io/introductory-errata/install